# Replace all images in folder with another image but keep filename

Tags: bash, terminal

Is there a way in OSX terminal to replace all images in a folder (they all have incremental filenames) with another image, but to maintain the original file name?

I've been googling for a long time but have not found anything useful.

For example, the following files need replacing:

```
1.jpg
239.jpg
213.jpg
5678.jpg
```

I need the file names to stay the same but say `default.jpg` to overwrite the image and then be renamed to match the image it had just replaced. So in theory:

```
n = file
x = filename
default = c://download/default.jpg
folder = c://downloads

For each n in folder
    x = get filename
    copy default to folder
    delete n
    rename default to x
Loop
```

So it will programmatically replace all of the files with the new image?

I really do not know where to start?

Comment: You tagged "terminal", but what's your platform? Are you trying to do this with a shell script? I've tagged "shell" for now, but please correct if wrong.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I'm using terminal on a Mac - I'll update my original question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So I tweaked the code a bit and got it to work without an error. for example:

```
for i in /Users/User/downloads/listings/m/folder4/newfolder/*.jpg; do cp -R /Users/User/downloads/listings/m/folder4/newfolder/default.jpg "$i"; done
```

Just in case anyone else needs to do this. Thanks for your comments and pointing me in the right direction.

Regards
D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe :

```
for i in *.jpg
do 
  cp default.jpg "$i"
done
```

That will issue an error once (when processing default.jpg) but should do the job.

Comment: To avoid the error, simply run a check before copying: `[ "$i" = "default.jpg" ] || cp default.jpg "$i"`.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on this: I have modified the code to match my setup as: for i in /Users/user/downloads/listings/m/newfolder do cp /Users/user/downloads/default.jpg "$i" done but I'm getting unexpected token done?